# Exposing an unbindable property to the ViewModel

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-8

I have a View with a [LongListMultiSelector](https://phone.codeplex.com/).  My ViewModel needs to access the SelectedItems property which is not available for binding.  Without exposing my View to my ViewModel, how do I expose it?

Comment: Maybe the control exposes an event, say, `SelectionChanged`, that you can handle? From an event handler, you can access the view model through the `DataContext` property.

Comment: I don't know why I was so blinded to that option.  I just kept trying to make binding work.  Thanks.  I'd still like to know if there are any ways to solve this problem using binding, even if it requires some  hacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232725/wp8-longlistselector-selecteditem-not-bindable/15239833#15239833) from someone also trying to accomplish the same thing has the solution.

Comment: The LongListSelector is a bit different from LongListMultiSelector, though. Replacing base.SelectedItem = with base.SelectedItems = is invalid as SelectedItems is only a gettable property in LongListMultiSelector.

Comment: Yes you would need to provide a custom implementation similar to the one found on the blog post linked from that other question.