# ListPicker no longer works in my Windows Phone 8 application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a WIndows Phone application. This application had been running fine in WIndows Phone 7.5. However, I needed to make some updates. So I decided to use the latest toolkit. When I decided to make that change, my ListPicker stopped working. I have the following code:

```
<tk:ListPicker x:Name="typeListPicker" Grid.Row="7" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyTypes}" 
  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedType, Mode=TwoWay}" 
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource typeTemplate}" 
  FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource fullTypeTemplate}" Margin="12,-2,12,0">
</tk:ListPicker>
```

Currently, MyTypes has 10 items in it. Due to the size of this collection, the Full Mode is displayed. When I select an item though, I am not taken back to the screen where the ListPicker is at. Instead, I am taken back to the Page that hosts the screen I am showing. Oddly, I do not see an exception being thrown or anything if that nature.

To confirm my suspicions, I removed several of the items from MyTypes down to a collection of 3 items. This way, full mode would not be displayed. When I did this, my screen worked as desired. I can't figure out why Full Mode is no longer working in my app. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep seeing different variations of this problem over and over on here.

Your problem is with SelectedItem not being a notifiable (not bind-able) property in Windows Phone 8.

The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889564/exposing-an-unbindable-property-to-the-viewmodel/15890090#15890090) will lead you to the solution along with explaining what is going on.